# Why does Teradata throw "Too many data records packed in one USING row" ONLY sometimes ??

Tags: teradata

I am using `jdbc` and uploading data to Teradata. I used to have 100,000 rows of batch previously and it **ALWAYS** worked fine for me. **No dataset failed uploading EVER !**

Now, I tried to upload a `one column table (all integers)` ,  I get this `Too many data records packed in one USING row` ? As I changed the batch to `16,383` it worked .

I found out that I am still able to use `100,000` rows batch for tables with `multiple columns`, however when I try to upload a table with a `single column`, it throws `Too many data records packed in one USING row`  . . . I just can't understand why ? Intuitively , a single column table should be easier to upload right ? What is going on here ?

Answer (score 2):

16383 is the limit for a PreparedStatement using a non-FastLoad INSERT for Teradata JDBC.

Have you considered adding TYPE=FASTLOAD to your connection parameters and allowing Teradata to invoke the FastLoad API to bulk load your data for INSERT statements that are supported by FastLoad? The **[JDBC FastLoad](http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/jdbcug_chapter_2.html#BABFGFAF)** mechanism is suggested for inserts of 100K records or more. The big factor here is that your target table in Teradata must be empty.

If it isn't empty then you may be able to load an empty stage table that you in turn use the ANSI MERGE operator to perform an UPSERT of the stage data to the target table.

Comment: Thank you. I used Fastload, but there are two issues with it : 1) Text qualifier are supported ONLY by TTU14, I have 14 but it does not work for some reason 2) `too many unload . . operations ` error

Comment: In addition, I tested this http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/samp/T20205JD.java.txt  . . the fastload works fine on samples less than 200K , but it fails for bigger samples because of `OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` . I can increase the heap `xlx6g  . . ` but that results in slower execution of `pstmt.addBatch()` . It looks like `Prepared Statements` work better, and Fastload sucks

Comment: Have you considered take the data as a flat file and running it through a standalone version of FastLoad, MultiLoad or Teradata Parallel Transport? Given the utilities have their nuances but they can load data very effectively.

Comment: This requires capability of writing procedures, right ? I found only one source online https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDcQFjAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fteradataworld.wordpress.com%2Fteradata-parallel-transporter-tpt%2F&ei=CJRSVKq6I8G2yATpt4HwDQ&usg=AFQjCNETaYJGpO0jcBJ35WgJNXIdEArWig&bvm=bv.78597519,d.aWw could you recommend any other sources

Comment: Stored procedures? No.